# ¿Como puedo enlazar a DisplayMemberPath dentro de un ItemTemplate?

Tags: .net, xaml, wpf

Necesito crear un control de tipo lista que cumpla con los siguientes requisitos:

- Mostrar un icono eliminar justo al lado del texto de cada ítem.
- Debe de mostrar en horizontal los elementos agregados.
- Al pulsar en el icono eliminar, el control debe ser capaz eliminarlo del ItemsSource, y estos cambios deben de ser reflejados también a la propiedad a la que esté enlazada el ItemsSource.
- Debe de funcionar siempre, independientemente del tipo enlazado a la propiedad ItemsSource del control.

Para ello he realizado un custom control que hereda de listview:

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class ListCustomControl
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.ListView

Shared Sub New()
    'Esta llamada a OverrideMetadata indica al sistema que este elemento desea proporcionar un estilo diferente al de su clase base.
    'Este estilo se define en themes\generic.xaml
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(ListCustomControl), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(ListCustomControl)))
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub OnApplyTemplate()
    MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()
End Sub

Private Sub ListCustomControl_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    AddHandler MyBase.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, AddressOf OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown
End Sub

Private Overloads Sub OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    If e.OriginalSource.GetType Is GetType(Controls.Image) Then
        CType(Me.ItemsSource, IList).Remove(CType(e.OriginalSource, Image).DataContext)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

He aquí el generic.xaml asociado a ListCustomControl:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ListCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ListCustomControl}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="ItemTemplate">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                    Padding="2"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="LabelText"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LabelTextColor}"
                            Content="{Binding Name}" 
                            Padding="2,0,2,0"
                            FontStyle="Italic" />
                        <Border x:Name="PART_IconBorder"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="White" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            BorderBrush="White">
                            <Image x:Name="Icon"
                            Stretch="None"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Source="/ListCustomControl;component/Resources/Images/delete.gif" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Todo funciona cumpliendo los requisitos solicitados, pero me queda una duda:

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el content del labeltext funcionara contra la propiedad DisplayMemberPath de ListCustomControl en lugar de estar obligado a enlazarlo a la propiedad name como está ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar algo como esto:

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListCustomControl}}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}"/>
```

Lo que hace es buscar al contenedor superior que coincide con el tipo 'ListCustomControl' y toma su propiedad 'DisplayMemberPath', siempre que esté definida ahí, sino no mostrará nada.